# In NetSuite How to Hide custom subtab using client script?

Tags: netsuite

is it possible to hide custom subtab on field change event of client script in Netsuite?
If there is any solution avilable then help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the subtab's id from the source. In my basic example below, I hide the shipping tab on a transaction when entity is changed.

```
function hideTabFieldChanged(type, name, linenum) {
    if (name == 'entity'){
        $('#shippinglnk').hide();
    }
}
```